# Protecting symbols against redefinition by Mathematica?

Tags: internals

Just spent an hour to isolate my crashes to the following unintuitive behavior. `SemidefiniteProgramming` redefines the $\otimes$ symbol...but only the first time it is called. I've been using this symbol for my Kronecker products to keep implementations small.

Is there some way I can get an error or warning when Mathematica redefines my symbols? Alternatively, is there another symbol that I should perhaps use instead of $\otimes$ to avoid this?

This is for Mathematica 12.1.0.0 on Mac.

````
Unprotect[TensorProduct];
TensorProduct = KroneckerProduct;
Protect[TensorProduct];
ii = IdentityMatrix[2];

Print[ii\[TensorProduct]ii]; (* prints {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}} *)
SemidefiniteOptimization[x, {x > 0}, {x}];
Print[ii\[TensorProduct]ii]; (* prints {{{{1,0},{0,1}},{{0,0},{0,0}}},{{{0,0},{0,0}},{{1,0},{0,1}}}} *)
```
````

Comment: Why not use CircleTimes instead?

Comment: Good idea....looks the same and doesn't have built-in meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct;` and enter it using :c*: